# COBOLのCALL文のコンパイル方法

Tags: cobol

vagrantを使用したcentos6.5
opencobol1.0
という仕様でcobolの勉強をしています。
CALL文を使用した際のサブルーチンのコンパイル方法がわかりません。

今までのコンパイルは「cobc -x --free ファイル名」
という形でできたのですが、サブルーチン側のコンパイルをしようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。何かコンパイル方法に違いがあるのでしょうか？

ソースはこちら
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/cobol_subroutines.htm
を参考にし、MAIN.cob、SUB.cobという名前で作成した後

```
$ cobc -x --free MAIN.cob
$ cobc -x --free SUB.cob
```

とすると、

> SUB.cob:10: Error: Executable program requested but PROCEDURE/ENTRY has USING clause

というエラーが発生します。

SUB.cobの中は

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. UTIL.

DATA DIVISION.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 LS-STUDENT-ID PIC 9(4).
   01 LS-STUDENT-NAME PIC A(15).

PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LS-STUDENT-ID, LS-STUDENT-NAME.
   DISPLAY 'In Called Program'.
   MOVE 1111 TO LS-STUDENT-ID.
EXIT PROGRAM.
```

このようになってます。お分かりになる方よろしくおねがいいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[依存性がある](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/cobol_subroutines.htm)ようですので、すべての関連したファイルを**一緒に**コンパイルする必要があると思います。`OpenCOBOL`の場合は、別々でコンパイルしたら、`SUB`から`MAIN`までのリンクが作られないようですね。あと、コンパイルする前に、コマンドのファイルの順序にご注意ください。

この場合は、`OpenCOBOL`で[下記](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29109331/1167750)のコマンドはどうでしょうか。

```
cobc -x --free MAIN.cob SUB.cob
```

出力は：

```
$ ./MAIN 
In Called Program
Student Id : 1111
Student Name : Tim
```

Comment: あっっっさりできました。小さなことだけどなかなかわからないものですね、ありがとうございました。